# How do I increment value based on value in column and everytime I increment return the value to another column. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently doing a data analysis internship at a small company and I have to clean up some data using python and pandas. One of the requests was to add a column that has device #1 in correlating with Site #... So when Site # is 0 device #1 is in the following column and when Site # is 1 device #2 is in the following column. The kicker is the device number increases throughout the 350,000 rows and I need to increment the device # up everytime I come across the next set of device numbers. Before the next set of device #'s so in this case 3,4 which is after 1,2 there is a cell with '======' that I use as an indicator to increment up to 3,4 and so on. However I can never get my code to properly increment up to the next set of device #'s when it comes across the indicator.

```
def z(x):
    b=1
    if df['Site'] != '======':
        x == 0: return b
        x == 1: return b + 1
    if df['Site'] == '======':
        b += 2
df['Device #'] = df['Site'].apply(z)
```

Comment: Please could you add a small example dataset and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

This is how this is done:

```
b=0
def increment(i):

    global b

    if i == 0:
        return i

    elif i == "=====":
        b += 2 
        i += b
    
    elif i ==1:
        i += 1
    
    return i

df["Device #"] = df["Site"].map(increment)
```

Or if you insist on using `apply`, you can do it this way:

```
df["Device #"] = df["Site"].apply(increment, axis = 1)
```

Comment: I need to increment i when df['Site'] = '======' and if df['site'] == 0 return b and if df['Site'] == 1 return b + 1 then when it passes '======' b is incremented and the value of b increases. I tried your code with this in mind but it's not working, b wont increment everytime it sees '======'

Comment: The counter increases by 2 when i is ===== and increases by 1 when i = 1 and does nothing when i = 0. Is that correct?

Comment: So my rows in the dataframe are broken up by device # so for example, device #1,2, device #3,4 and this goes on till device #999,1000. We test each device in site 0 and site 1, when the df['Site'] = 0 I need it to equal the first device number out of the two in it's section so for device #1,2 when site = 0 device # = 1 and when site = 1 device #2 and I need to do this up to device #999,1000 so by the end when site = 0 device # = 999 and when site = 1 device# = 1000. Each set of device numbers is broken up by '======'

Comment: I am using '======' as an indicator to know that it's time to switch to the next set of device #'s so I need to increment b+=2 when I iterate down the 'Site' column and see '======'. Once I increment b+=2 to the next set of numbs i return b if x = 0 and return b + 1 if x = 1. So that it goes from device# 1,2 to 3,4 to 5,6 and so on.

Comment: Check the new updated solution. Also, do you want ===== to act as a counter that's value is stored? As in: If x is ===== once, the incremented value is 2, twice it adds 4 to x, thrice it adds 6 to x, and so on. Or do you just want it to add 2 to x each time, the same as when site = 1 you just add 1 to x?

Comment: Hello, the solution you provided worked. I can't think you enough. How do i commend you for your efforts? I don't see an option for me to rate your work or your page.